# Displaying as html table from grouped array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the array items grouped using JavaScript and i am expecting this grouped array items to be displayed as HTML table.

```
{
      "Maruti": {
        "petrol": [
          {
            "name": "X1",
            "price": "rupees",
            "seats": "6"
          },
          {
            "name": "F1",
            "price": "rupees",
            "seats": "7"
          }
        ],
        "Disel": [
          {
            "name": "E1",
            "price": "rupees",
            "seats": "5"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Toyato": {
        "Disel": [
          {
            "name": "R3",
            "price": "rupees",
            "seats": "6"
          },
          {
            "name": "G4",
            "price": "rupees",
            "seats": "4"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Kia": {
        "petrol": [
          {
            "name": "W5",
            "price": "rupees",
            "seats": "6"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

i have tried something like below but unable to get an idea on how to display the sub elements

[image]

Comment: what is `item.manu` ? Is `<td>` without a closing tag valid? Also, don't append inside forEach!

Comment: Have you tried to google how to loop objects and arrays?

Comment: Sorry i am not a full time developer and not sure on how to find using the exact terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the table with 3 columns, and then keep the number of rows aligned while you populate the table column by column. It is matter of iterating the nested data with `for` loops or iterating array methods, and using the appropriate DOM methods for extending the table as you go...

Use CSS classes for the formatting:

```js
function populateTable(table, data) {
    let colCount = Object.keys(data).length;
    let tableRows = table.rows;

    table.innerHTML = ""; // clear table before starting
    
    function setCell(row, col, cssClass, text) {
        while (row >= table.rows.length) {
            let row = table.insertRow();
            for (let i = 0; i < colCount; i++) row.insertCell();
        }
        let cell = table.rows[row].cells[col];
        cell.className = cssClass;
        cell.textContent = text;
    }
    
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([brand, brandData], col) => {
        setCell(0, col, "brand", brand);
        let row = 0;
        Object.entries(brandData).forEach(([fuel, fuelData]) => {
            setCell(++row, col, "fuel", fuel);
            for (let {name} of fuelData) {
                setCell(++row, col, "", name);
            }
        });
    });
}

// Example data
let result = {"Maruti": {"Petrol": [{"name": "X1","price": "rupees","seats": "6"},{"name": "F1","price": "rupees","seats": "7"}],"Diesel": [{"name": "E1","price": "rupees","seats": "5"}]},"Toyota": {"Diesel": [{"name": "R3","price": "rupees","seats": "6"},{"name": "G4","price": "rupees","seats": "4"}]},"Kia": {"Petrol": [{"name": "W5","price": "rupees","seats": "6"}]}};
populateTable(document.querySelector("#table"), result);
```

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid grey; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.brand {
    background: silver;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.fuel {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```